# How do I find my unclosed parentheses start with GCC?

Tags: c, gcc

I've got a lot of source code in front of me (almost 500 lines) and GCC keeps throwing an error that it didn't expect my brackets at the end of my function declaration because it expected a parenthesis instead.  I can't see the unclosed parenthesis myself, and GCC isn't telling me where the expected character's match is on its own (only where the character was expected).  What arguments could I pass to GCC to get it to tell me where it is?

Comment: If I don't find where the unclosed parenthesis is then I can't fix it, and GCC is being too vague.

Comment: Which editor are you using to view the code?

Comment: This is usually more easily done in the text editor or IDE, not the compiler.

Comment: You could try clang, it often has more useful error messages

Comment: Many editors often has functionality to auto-indent code. Use that functionality and you will easily see where brackets may be missing.

Comment: Okay I just commented out pthread_cleanup_push(&interpreter_cleanup, arg) and replaced that with zero, and all the errors disappeared.  Very odd.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use an auto indenter. When the number of brackets is wrong, the auto indentation will stop to work around that line.

Comment: The text editors I use (nano, gedit) either do not feature that functionality or I am not aware of such.

Comment: Also, my problem is I can't find an unclosed parenthesis.